# How to delete persistent model objects?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swift-data

I have a very simple project, it currently consists of a model of clients, and a list of those clients. Quite simple.

I am getting this error: Instance method 'delete' requires that '[Client]' conform to 'PersistentModel' on the swipe action to delete.

```
@Model
class Client {
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var jobDate: Date
    
    init(name: String, address: String, jobDate: Date) {
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.jobDate = jobDate
    }
}
```

```
struct RootView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query(sort: \Client.name) var clients: [Client]
    let newClient = [Client]()
    
    @State private var showingAddClient = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach(clients, id: \.self) { client in
                    NavigationLink {
                        EditView(clients: client)
                    } label: {
                        Text(client.name)
                    }
                }
                .swipeActions {
                    Button("Delete", systemImage: "trash", role: .destructive) {
                        modelContext.delete(clients)
                    }
                }
            }

 func delete(_ indexSet: IndexSet) {
        for i in indexSet {
            let client = clients[i]
            modelContext.delete(client)
        }
    }
   
}
```

More than a solution, if someone can offer suggestions on how or steps you use to troubleshoot these types of issues I would be grateful. This is all new to me and learning how what steps more experienced programmers use to deduce errors is really helpful as I don't know where to start.

Comment: it could be a typo. Are you meaning to just delete one `client`, such as: `modelContext.delete(client)` , note no `s`. The `modelContext.delete()` probably does not take an array as argument.

Comment: thanks. i have tried 'client' but that gives me the error it cannot be found in scope.

Comment: try replacing your `List/ForEach` with just `List(clients, id: \.self) { client in ...` and have `swipeActions` inside the `List`

Comment: that still shows the same error, same deal too when i try just 'client'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the problem by modifying the approach to deleting. I still don't fully understand why the initial way wasn't working but after reviewing apples docs, this solution worked.

```
NavigationStack {
        List {
            ForEach(clients, id: \.self) { client in
                NavigationLink {
                    EditView(clients: client)
                } label: {
                    Text(client.name)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
```

with a function of:

```
private func delete(at indexSet: IndexSet) {
    for index in indexSet {
        modelContext.delete(clients[index])
    }
}
```